# Swiper.js visible 3 slides need to have different width

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUytw.jpg)
Here is how it looks like now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HldaP.jpg)
How it should looks like, perfectly aligned with the box below.

Here is my current config.

```
<Swiper
                    className="mySwiper2 bg-white text-white"
                    modules={[Navigation, Pagination, EffectFade]}
                    spaceBetween={20}
                    freeMode
                    centeredSlides={true}
                    parallax={true}

                    breakpoints={{
                        250: {
                            slidesPerView: 1.1,
                            spaceBetween: 10
                        },
                        640: {
                            slidesPerView: 1.1,
                            spaceBetween: 20,
                        },
                        1024: {
                            slidesPerView: 1.5,
                            spaceBetween: 20,
                        }
                    }}
                    loop={true}
                >
```

Comment: Your Q is not clear.

Comment: @EzraSiton have you seen the images? If so can I contact you privately?